# What Technique of Integration would be most efficient?

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the integral: $$\int {\sin(4x)\over\cos^3(4x)+\cos(4x)} dx$$

Comment: Substitution is a good way to start: $u = \cos(4x) \implies {\rm d}u = -4\sin(4x){\rm d}x$. Then decompose the resulting integral in partial fractions.

Comment: I agree! Begin with substitution, followed by partial fractions to evaluate the subsequent integrals. Is this indeed the most efficient manner?

Comment: It is very simple and works. What more can you ask for?

Comment: Fair enough. Nice dicussion!

Comment: Once the substitution is carried out, the integral can be evaluated without partial fraction decomposition...